# No Android Project option in Eclipse with ADT Plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm an experienced programmer and android user. I'm following a guide for creating the android project in eclipse from the android developer site, and I've followed every step up to creating the project, and the ADT plugin has been correctly installed and configured. The problem: Under the android tab in the new project wizard there is no option for android project. There are various other android options like Android Activity, Android Application Project, Android Icon Set, etc. Does anybody know how I can enable the option for Android Project? I have searched this site, along with various others, and nobody seems to have the same problem. Here is a link to an XDA post I made about this problem: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1747568. I attached a picture of the problem. Thank you! Here is a picture of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mRFi.png

Comment: The problem is the guide on the Android developer site is not exactly updated with the newer ADT plugin. Its there right in front of you - *Android Application Project*...

Comment: Thank you, they should update that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest ADT (20) a few changes were made to the UI and the tutorials in the Android Training section are a bit out of date. You are probably looking for 'Android Application Project'.

Answer (score 2):

An Android Application Project is an Android Project.